# type hinting/documenting/extension of a Cython lib

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, cython

I've updated some of the type hinting/documentation in a lib called `pygrib`. The source documentation
can be found [here](https://jswhit.github.io/pygrib/api.html).

The goal is to extend the `Cython` api with the associated native type hints and maintain an open ended platform for future growth, IE more methods like `to_dataframe()`

`pygrib` uses `Cython` to read gridded binary files `grib`

#### `pygrib2.__init__.py`

```py
from .core import *
from .extension import *
```

#### `pygrib2.core.py`

```py
import os
from pygrib2.extension import File


class Reader:
    """reader wrapper with typing support around the pygrib open function"""
    grib_file: File

    def __init__(self, file_path: str):

        def _unzip(path: str) -> str:
            os.system(f'gzip -d {path}')
            return path.strip('.gz')

        if file_path.endswith('.gz'):
            self.file_path = _unzip(file_path)
        else:
            self.file_path = file_path

    def __enter__(self) -> File:
        self.grib_file = File(self.file_path)
        return self.grib_file

    def __exit__(self, *_) -> None:
        self.grib_file.close()
```

#### `pygrib2.extension.py`

````
from typing import NewType, Type,  Union, Any
import pandas as pd
import pygrib

PyGribOpen = NewType('PyGribOpen', Type[pygrib.open])
PyGribMessage = NewType('PyGribMessage', Type[pygrib.gribmessage])


class Message:
    def __init__(self, message: PyGribMessage):
        self._message = message

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self._message)

    def __getattr__(self, key: str) -> Any:
        """>>> Message.keys()"""
        return self._message.__getattribute__(key)

    def __getitem__(self, key: Union[bytes, str]) -> Any:
        """>>> Message['values']"""
        return self._message.__getattribute__(key)


class File(pygrib.open):
    def __next__(self):
        """>>> next(GribFile)"""
        return Message(super().__next__())

    def __getitem__(self, key: Union[int, slice]):
        """>>> GribFile[1]"""
        return Message(super().__getitem__(key))

    def to_dataframe(self):
        return pd.DataFrame.from_records(dict(_full_message(grb)) for grb in self)


def _full_message(grb: Message):
    """
    ### usage

    ```
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        with grib.Reader(GRIB_FILE) as grbs:
            for grb in grbs:
                x = tuple(grib._full_message(grb))
                print(x)
    ```
    """
    for k in grb.keys():
        try:
            yield k, grb[k]

        except RuntimeError:
            print(k)
````

#### `pygrib2.extension.pyi`

```py
from typing import (
    Iterator,
    NewType,
    TypeVar,
    Tuple,
    Union,
    List,
    Any
)
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import numpy.typing as npt

FloatArray = npt.NDArray[np.float_]
NData = NewType('NData[float]', FloatArray)
NLats = NewType('NLat[float]', FloatArray)
NLons = NewType('NLon[float]', FloatArray)


class Message:

    """
    ### Grib message object.

    Each grib message has attributes corresponding to GRIB keys. 
    Parameter names are described by the name, shortName and paramID keys. 
    pygrib also defines some special attributes which are defined below


    ### Variables

    - messagenumber - The grib message number in the file.

    - projparams - A dictionary containing proj4 key/value pairs describing the grid. Set to None for unsupported grid types.

    - expand_reduced - If True (default), reduced lat/lon and gaussian grids will be expanded to regular grids when data is accessed via values key. 
    If False, data is kept on unstructured reduced grid, and is returned in a 1-d array.

    - fcstimeunits - A string representing the forecast time units (an empty string if not defined).

    - analDate - A python datetime instance describing the analysis date and time for the forecast. Only set if forecastTime and julianDay keys exist.

    - validDate - A python datetime instance describing the valid date and time for the forecast. Only set if forecastTime and julianDay keys exist, 
    and fcstimeunits is defined. If forecast time is a range, then validDate corresponds to the end of the range.
    """

    def data(
        self,
        lat1: int = ...,
        lat2: int = ...,
        lon1: int = ...,
        lon2: int = ...
    ) -> Tuple[NData, NLats, NLons]:
        """
        extract data, lats and lons for a subset region defined by the keywords lat1,lat2,lon1,lon2.

        The default values of lat1,lat2,lon1,lon2 are None, which means the entire grid is returned.

        If the grid type is unprojected lat/lon and a geographic subset is requested 
        (by using the lat1,lat2,lon1,lon2 keywords), then 2-d arrays are returned, otherwise 1-d arrays are returned.
        """

    def expand_grid(self, arg=True) -> None:
        """toggle expansion of 1D reduced grid data to a regular (2D) grid (on by default)."""

    def has_key(self, key: Any) -> bool:
        """tests whether a grib message object has a specified key."""

    def is_missing(self, key: Any) -> bool:
        """
        returns True if key is invalid or value associated with key is equal to 
        grib missing value flag (False otherwise)
        """

    def keys(self) -> List[str]:
        """return keys associated with a grib message in a list"""

    def latlons(self) -> Tuple[NLats, NLons]:
        """
        compute lats and lons (in degrees) of grid. Currently handles regular lat/lon, 
        global gaussian, mercator, stereographic, lambert conformal, albers equal-area,
        space-view, azimuthal equidistant, reduced gaussian, reduced lat/lon, lambert
        azimuthal equal-area, rotated lat/lon and rotated gaussian grids.

        Returns
        lats,lons numpy arrays containing latitudes and longitudes of grid (in degrees).
        """

    def tostring(self) -> bytes:
        """
        return coded grib message in a binary string.
        """

    def valid_key(self, key: str) -> bool:
        """
        tests whether a grib message object has a specified key, 
        it is not missing and it has a value that can be read
        """


class File:
    """extension class for `<class 'pygrib._pygrib.open'>`"""

    def close(self) -> None:
        """close GRIB file, deallocate C structures associated with class instance"""

    def message(self, num: int) -> Message:
        """retrieve N'th message in iterator. same as seek(N-1) followed by readline()."""

    def read(self, num: int = None) -> List[Message]:
        """
        read N messages from current position, returning grib messages instances in a list.
        If N=None, all the messages to the end of the file are read. 

        pygrib.open(f).read() is equivalent to list(pygrib.open(f)), 
        both return a list containing gribmessage instances for all the grib messages in the file f.
        """

    def tell(self) -> Union[int, None]: ...
    def seek(self, num: int) -> int: ...
    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[Message]: ...
    def __next__(self) -> Message: ...
    def __getitem__(self, key: Union[int, slice]) -> Message: ...
    def to_dataframe(self, **kwargs) -> pd.DataFrame: ...


Message = TypeVar('Message', bound=Message)
File = TypeVar("File", bound=File)
```

#### `main.py`

```
import numpy as np
import pygrib2 as grib
GRIB_FILE = 'data/ecmwf_tigge.grb'

if __name__ == '__main__':

    with grib.Reader(GRIB_FILE) as grib_file:
        assert isinstance(grib_file, grib.File)
        message = grib_file[1]
        assert isinstance(message, grib.Message)
        assert all(isinstance(d, np.ndarray) for d in message.data())
```

Comment: note that in python 3.10+, `Union[int, None]` or `Optional[int]` can be written as `int | None` ([PEP604](https://peps.python.org/pep-0604/))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Reader` method has a `grib_file` member that is missing from the class until `__enter__`. This is generally not advisable: some linters will tell you that it needs to be set in `__init__`. In that case, it would be hinted as an `Optional` and set to `None` until `__enter__` is called. However, the lighter-weight approach is to scrap your class entirely and make a method looking roughly like

```
@contextmanager
def read_grib(file_path: str) -> Iterator[File]:
    if file_path.endswith('.gz'):
        os.system(f'gzip -d {file_path}')
        file_path = file_path.strip('.gz')

    grib_file = File(self.file_path)
    try:
        yield grib_file
    finally:
        grib_file.close()
```

But there are other unadvisable bits in there: don't `os.system`, use `subprocess` instead; and preferably use [.with_suffix](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.with_suffix) on a `Path` instead of doing your own string manipulation.

Even more preferable than `subprocess` is calling into the built-in [gzip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html) support.

`Message` is so permissive as to be almost useless. If you know anything about the actual members on the interior `PyGribMessage`, you should be exposing that in your typehinting, because right now it's all `Any`.

Many of your functions are missing return typehints, including `_full_message`. I encourage you to run `mypy` on your source; when properly configured it will let you know about such things.

Comment: `If you know anything about the actual members on the interior PyGribMessage`.   Aren't the type hints exposed via the stub file.

Comment: `pygrib.gribmessage` is the interior type. Does it have well-defined members (in a stub or otherwise)? If so, the `Message` class is doing more harm than good.

Comment: It does not if my understanding is correct. https://github.com/jswhit/pygrib/blob/master/src/pygrib/_pygrib.pyx#L721  `class pygrib.message` begin at line 721

Comment: It does have some well-known members; read docs starting at _pygrib also defines some special attributes which are defined below_

Comment: Moreover, if https://confluence.ecmwf.int/display/ECC/GRIB+Keys is to be believed, that's an authoritative source for expected attributes.

Comment: can you elaborate on what a `well known member is`